# install XMLReader module extension ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, xmlreader, xmlwriter

Im working with a plugin that requires XMLReader, and XMLWriter PHP modules to be installed. So I need to activate the DOMDocument, XMLReader, and XMLWriter PHP modules.

So far i have tried :
`sudo apt install php-xmlwriter`

apparently is installed but the message still is displayed. Am i missing something else? another module?

Comment: According to PHP docs: `The XMLWriter extension was initially a PECL extension for PHP 5. It was later added to the PHP source (bundled) as of PHP 5.1.2. This extension is enabled by default.`

Comment: *but the message still is displayed* what is the message?

Comment: this is the message displayed: 
WP All Export requires XMLReader, and XMLWriter PHP modules to be installed.
These are standard features of PHP, and are necessary for WP All Export to write the files you are trying to export.
Please contact your web hosting provider and ask them to install and activate the DOMDocument, XMLReader, and XMLWriter PHP modules. @NigelRen

Comment: how can i Know if this is enabled? what command? im on ubuntu 18.04 and nginx @user1597430

Comment: `php -m` is your friend here

Comment: `libxml` should be in the output of `php -m` (at least, by [default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.requirements.php))

Comment: correct @user1597430 so this libxml is the one that contains those 2 modules?

Comment: @Luuk yes you are right is there, if it's enable then why am i getting this error?

Comment: I am suprised to see `xmlwriter` and `xmlreader` next to `libxml` on this page: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/server-configuration/    You are working with PHP7.0 (or newer?) And, you did do a reboot after installing?

Comment: @Luuk i have php 7.3 on my server. Thank you for the link. I am checking this documentation and let you know my findings. have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came to a simple answer for this. Just needed to install the following:
`sudo apt install php7.3-xml` and this included both modules needed.

Answer (score 3):

For PHP 7.4 There is no `php7-xmlreader` or `php7-xmlwriter` package shown using `apt-list`. Only `php7.4-xml` and `php7.4-xmlrpc` - installing these/restarting apache and running `php -m` shows that xml support (including reader/writer) is enabled.

```
sudo apt-get update && apt list php7*
sudo apt install -y php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc
sudo service apache2 restart
php -m
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install each xml extension: `php7-xml`, `php7-xmlreader` and `php7-xmlwriter`

Here is an example

```
apk add --update --no-cache \
php7 \

... HERE ARE OTHER EXTENSIONS ...

php7-xmlwriter \
php7-xmlreader
```